# Animated background positioning not working

Tags: javascript, html, background

I am trying to put an animated background behind everything I have already written in html, but it seems like the content will not go over the animated background, instead it will go under it.[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBYyM.png)

As I said earlier, I expected the content of the page to go ON the animated background (the animated background to be 1 layer behind the page's content)

Comment: I think what you're running into is a z-index or position issue, but without some code it's hard to tell. Can you add some of your HTML and CSS to your question?

Comment: this is main.html https://pastebin.com/Up2DD9VF